# Set Theory Notation: What does it mean to "\" one set with another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

[image]

What does the "\" operator mean in the above context?

Comment: For sets $A$ and $B$, $A\backslash B = \{x \in A : x \not \in B\}$. Effectively it means $A$ without $B$.

Comment: Cool thanks, could you phrase this in an answer so I can upvote and give you credit?

Comment: By the way, division is a forward-slash, not a backwards-slash.

Comment: @GiantTortoise1729 : One should write $A\setminus B$ rather than $A\backslash B$.  \setminus provides proper spacing, as do things like $+$ and $-$ and $\times$, since it's a binary operator. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Actually, $A\setminus B$ is overspaced for just these characters, and $A\backslash B$ looks better. However, the spacing of \setminus is better when the sets are complicated constructions, which is often the case.

Comment: @JohnBentin : Which of these do you think is better: $A+B$ or $A{+}B$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The former: it's standard, and the laterally extensive plus sign is better at this spacing (although my taste would be for slightly narrower spacing). In the olden days, when mathematics was set by typesetters, the best typesetters would vary the spacing around operators according to context. Now, in LaTex, it's "one size fits all" for simplicity.

Comment: @JohnBentin : LaTeX isn't one-size-fits-all.  In LaTeX, the spacing depends on the context.  I suspect that is true of MathJax as well.  (What is used here is obviously not LaTeX, but people keep calling it that.)

Comment: QUOTE  the best typesetters would vary the spacing around operators according to context. Now, in LaTex, it's "one size fits all" END QUOTE.  That is utter nonsense.  You can't have used LaTeX much if you think it's not context-dependent in LaTeX.